# how to get aggregations on two or more fields in elasticsearch index to get the unique values in single bucket

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In MySql we have distinct Query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (Field1 ,Field2) FROM Table_Name;
```

Do we have the same replica of this  sql statement in Elastic-search aggregations? 
to get two fields term aggregation in single bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out.es

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5100